# Drop Down for content Heading

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

My customer want a FAQ page like in this link https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/faq.aspx

Pls suggest how can I achieve these **Drop downs** in SharePoint.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far. StackOverlfow is **not** a "This has to be done, *you* give me the answer site"

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery UI accordion for this.
See: https://jqueryui.com/accordion

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link could help you, all you need is Accordion Menu.
[ACCORDION JQUERY](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the link below where you can find a step-by-step sample of using CSR to show your SharePoint List View using Accordion control:

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html

Answer (score 1):

Another simple out of box solution will be to create **Group by view** for your FAQ list.

Steps will be as below

1. Create a custom list with Column "**Question**" and "**Answer**" and name the list as FAQ
2. Add your Question and Answers in this list
3. Now create group by view on column **Question**

Here is video tutorial on creating group by view: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWHiRCJ7fVM

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example : Source code is avaialbe : [Hope this helps](http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-an-accordion-with-html-css-jquery)