# Is there any good/pro FAQ structure or should I use lists and change the code ?

Tags: list

I need to implement a FAQ for my sharepoint and I only found FAQ as lists which got modified. Is there an other way to do it? Otherwise can you give me guidance or a process? Thank you

Comment: Similar discussion here. May give you some idea. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150388/drop-down-for-content-heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and most useful way of creating a FAQ is (as you mention) to modify a Custom List where the field Title is the Question and You create a new Field/Site Column named Answer and set its type to "Multiple Lines of text". You can also (on the Properties/Settings of the list click on "Rating Settings"  and configure it so that it will be able for Your users to rate the topics.